# How to kill a GNU `screen` session programatically?

Tags: bash

i need the following thing

lets say i have an attached screen "MY_Screen_name" and a running process inside that screen. I would like to kill "MY_Screen_name" and the running process inside then run another script.

is it going to be this way ?

```
#!/bin/sh
st_user="myuser"
chown $st_user -R

screen -S MY_Screen_name -X stuff ^C
screen -S MY_Screen_name -X stuff ^X

sleep 5

cd /path/to/myscript
./my_script.sh
```

Comment: How about with `killall -9 MY_Screen_name` and check it `sudo ps -auxf|grep MY_Screen_name`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command,

```
$ kill -9 My_Screen_name
```

After that, you can check the Screen Status using the command,

```
$ sudo ps -auxf|grep My_Screen_name
```

Currently running or closed!!